# Text over picture can only be in one word. When it@s two words or more, the second word drop down and slightly overlaps the first word

Tags: html, css

I have a picture as a background and a h2 header above the picture. But I cant have headings with more than one word without the second word dropping down.

Not sure why it does this and how to fix it.

[image: Image of the overlapping heading]

```css
#forsidebilde {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#showcasetittel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50‰;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  min-height: 300px;
  font-size: 5em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase">
  <img id="forsidebilde" src="bilder/forsidebilde.jpg" alt="Bilde av fjell og     fjord.">
  <h2 id="showcasetittel">Velkommen</h2>
</div>
<section id="main">
```

Comment: Your HTML as posted is malformed and this does not reproduce the issue in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your browser's Inspect Element tool, you should be able to see the width of your h2. I have the feeling it's forcing a line break because the element isn't able to expand to contain the text on one line, so it breaks the line at the space. You might be able to use the `&nbsp;` special character code between the h2 words to prevent it from breaking onto two lines.

The reason the text is overlapping is, I believe, because the line-height property is less than the height of the text. Try experimenting with different line heights to see if that helps.